# How to I use ag to search only in current folder (nonrecursive)?

Tags: ag

I love  [`ag :: the_silver_searcher`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) but I am wondering how can I perform a search non-recursively.

Sometimes I want to search only inside files from my home directory but without looking in subdirectories.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check the depth option from the manual :

> --depth NUM : Search up to NUM directories deep, -1 for unlimited. Default is 25.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. It seems that I lost my ability to properly RTFM.

Comment: Note that Emacs's **helm-ag** requires the use of the = separator for the long option, e.g. for current directory: `--depth=0`